How to verify that element is not visible in webdriverio in mocha javascript
I am currently automating tasks in JavaScript using the WebdriverIO framework with Mocha
How can I verify that an element is not visible in WebdriverIO within the Mocha framework?
I want Javascript Code which can verify element Is not visible on UI.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To verify that an element is not visible in WebdriverIO with Mocha, you can use the isDisplayed() method provided by WebdriverIO. This method returns a boolean value indicating whether the element is visible or not. If the element is not present in the DOM, it will throw an error, so you may want to use the isExisting() method first to check for its existence and then check for visibility if it exists.
